# Difference between serialization and writing and reading data structures to a binary file?

Tags: file, object, serialization, file-io, data-structures

Serialization is kind of like storing data objects to enable us to transfer them anywhere but how is different from just simply writing a object or data structure to a binary file ...???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization is another - more formal, if you will - way of saying that you are generating a representation of an object or data structure and storing it somewhere. The destination for storage could be: be file, a database, another location in memory etc.

The name **serialization** implies that the contents/state of the object or the data structure will will be represented sequentially (serially) which is how computer memory is fundamentally organized: *as a series of bytes*.

Serialization is an abstract **concept/process** and in the general sense does not imply a specific representation. You might have a binary representation (binary serialization) or a text representation (XML or JSON to name a few) and potentially others. Even binary serialization can be accomplished in many ways as far as how the information about the object or data structure is organized.

The opposite of serialization is **deserialization** which takes a serialized representation of an object or data structure and re-creates, or restores the state, of the object or data structure into a usable form.

Comment: we can still maintain such an order while writing to a binary file right??

Comment: @SayanPaul - yes, of course. Writing an object or data strucutre to a binary file is just one possible way to serialize it.

Comment: What would you say about function naming, for example, "deserialize_cat_from_db" vs "read_cat_from_db"?